# How to make an html nav bar that is centered but also responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a nav bar for my website that is centered but also responsive. If you run my code snippet and look at it in the full page and you make the width of the website really small you will notice that the links go away and a icon appears on the top right corner. When you click on the icon the links will reappear in a different fashion. Ive tried numerous different things to try to center my nav bar. However, it mostly just messed up my nav bar completely. I know how to center a nav bar without it being responsive. But I really like how its responsive as I think it would look really good on a mobile phone. If anyone could give me some tips it would be much appreciated!

```css
 .topnav {
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333;
            }
              
              .topnav a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
              }
              
              .topnav a:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
                color: black;
              }
              
              .topnav a.active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
              }
              
              .topnav .icon {
                display: none;
              }
              
               @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
                .topnav a.icon {
                  float: right;
                  display: block;
                }
              }
              
              @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
                .topnav.responsive .icon {
                  position: absolute;
                  right: 0;
                  top: 0;
                }
                .topnav.responsive a {
                  float: none;
                  display: block;
                  text-align: left;
                }
              }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#news" class="active">HOME</a>
            <a href="#news">SERVICES</a>
            <a href="#contact">PRODUCTS</a>
            <a href="#news">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="#news">CALCULATORS</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

      <script>
      function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
              if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
              } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
              }
            }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to center the menu items for both desktop & mobile layout? Or both? You can help viewers understand the issue by attaching an image of the desired output.

Comment: centered for desktop but if the width is too small then it displays just the home and the Icon. For mobile just the home and the Icon.

Comment: Since you already copy-paste w3schools example - check this one also: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#news" class="active">HOME</a>
    <a href="#news">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="#contact">PRODUCTS</a>
    <a href="#news">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#news">CALCULATORS</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to to your `head`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

My apologies. I didn't make it to my desktop in time to edit my response.

Comment: I am not seeing your suggestion. What do you think I should add to the head?

Answer (score 0):

If by centering you mean the  tag elements inside the collapsed bar, you are setting "text-align" property to "left" by changing it to "center", it will center the navbar items.

- You are using same media query twice no need to do that, put the other code in single query as you are not altering screen width.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }

  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```